# HTTP Error 404 when accessing nifi

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, apache-nifi

When accessing nifi, I keep getting an HTTP error.  It seems a page is missing. Where can I find this page?

Here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache NiFi has a working directory that Jetty uses to explode the embedded web applications into. Could the contents of those directories been accidentally removed?

The Jetty working directory is defined by the `nifi.web.jetty.working.directory` property.

Any other details you can share would help (version of NiFi, version of Java, JRE or JDK, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  It seems it was simply a hard drive space error!